# Magento Product Attribute - Multiple Fields

Tags: magento, text, attributes, field

We are making a new website with Magento and in that case I needed to create an attribute set which should contain multiple text fields. Problem is, when creating the attribute, I'm only allowed to insert 1 text field?

For us, in this situation, it would be perfect to have a button like 'Add text field' and it would add another row to echo out on our frontend.

The content of those text fields varies from product to product.

I've been searching, but can't seem to find anything.

Someone have an idea of what I should be searching for or start doing?

Thanks!